# How to decode JSON where the values are separated in lines

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have this JSON encoded text:

```
{"port":27277,"velocityX":-0.4,"time":199888,"powerup":"Wall","player":0,"positionX":2331,"velocityY":4.2,"positionY":1130,"type":"powerupUse"}
{"port":27277,"velocityX":0,"time":199921,"powerup":"Homing Missile","player":0,"positionX":2319,"velocityY":0,"positionY":1179,"type":"powerupPickup"}
{"port":27277,"time":200032,"type":"pingSummary","pingByPlayer":{"0":0}}
{"port":27277,"velocityX":0.37,"time":201784,"powerup":"Homing Missile","player":0,"positionX":2346.61,"velocityY":4.25,"positionY":1123.58,"type":"powerupUse"}
{"port":27277,"time":202623,"player":0,"target":"turret","xp":1,"type":"structureDamage","exactXp":1.8466638326644897}
{"port":27277,"time":202623,"player":0,"target":"turret","xp":10,"type":"structureDestroy"}
{"port":27277,"time":202936,"player":0,"target":"turret","xp":2,"type":"structureDamage","exactXp":2.9056427478790283}
{"port":27277,"time":203171,"player":0,"target":"turret","xp":4,"type":"structureDamage","exactXp":4.7512664794921875}
{"port":27277,"time":205034,"type":"pingSummary","pingByPlayer":{"0":0}}
```

I  want to decode it in Python and I've tried this:

```
with open("log.txt") as log:
    data = log.read()
    jsondata = json.loads(data)
```

But I get this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 82)
```

I want to parse data like

```
['port']['time']['player']
```

Could someone help me with this because I need this soon?

Comment: In your example input each line is a valid json document, so you should split your input on each newline and parse them seperatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
import json

jsondata = 0

with open("log.txt") as log_file:
    jsondata = [json.loads(line) for line in log_file]

for line in jsondata:
    if 'port' in line:
        print("Port: {}".format(line['port']))
    if 'time' in line:
        print("Time: {}".format(line['time']))
    if 'player' in line:
        print("Player: {}".format(line['player']))
```

Comment: Can you provide link to your log.txt file, as I just copied it and pasted in txt file for testing ? Maybe file is not good formatted, as this runs perfectly on my machine...

Comment: sure, the lines I've posted are just few of the file! https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/145631855947939841/193366587917598721/log.txt

Comment: I studied your file, and I have to tell you that your JSON is invalid. Go and manually check mistake by mistake, as I tried to encode it, and even after that json.loads fails.

Answer (score 4):

`json.loads` loads *a single JSON object*. In your case, `log.txt` contains multiple JSON objects separated by `"\n"`. You can iterate over the lines in the file and call `json.loads` on each of them:

```
with open("log.txt") as log:
    jsondata = [json.loads(line) for line in log]
```

Comment: @StamKaly, if you iterate over a file object (either explicitly with `[... for line in log]` or implicitly with `map(json.loads, log)`, the file will be read. Iterating over a file object reads it line-by-line and yield each and every line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have more jsons in the file, not only one. Split the text with "\n" separator and then call json.loads for every row.